# What is the params hash in rails and how to use it and change it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

What is the difference between params[:id] and params[:zombie_id]?
what is that :id in the params hash?
What about params[:zombie]?

Comment: Consider reading a tutorial. This is not undocumented magic. (The reason[s] for not modifying it should become clear.)

Answer (score 4):

I'd prefer you read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html first.

`params` refer the list of request parameters passed to your controller action.

you can pass zombie_id as, `your_valid_routing_path(:zombie_id=>1)`

:id in params generally in rails refer to the 'member' which you are refering to

e.g.

`link_to profile_obj`

by default would route something like, `/profile/4` where 4 is profile_obj.id

and in your action you can access 4 using params[:id]